# How to calculate the trace below?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, dirac-matrices, trace

I am currently reading Peskin's QFT book on my own. Though it introduces the Trace Technology in Section 5.1, the trace calculations in the following sections are still far from clear to me.

Here is what I am stuggling now

$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{tr} \left[p' \!\!\!\!/ \gamma ^{\mu}k \!\!/ \gamma ^{ \nu}p \!\!/ \gamma _{ \nu} k \!\!/ \gamma _{ \mu}\right] & =  \mathrm{tr} \left[ \left(-2 p' \!\!\!\!/\right) k \!\!/ \left(-2 p \!\!/\right)k \!\!/\right]\\
& =  \mathrm{tr} \left[4 p' \!\!\!\!/ k \!\!/ \left(2 p \cdot k - k \!\!/ p \!\!/\right)\right]\\
& = 8 p \cdot k \ \mathrm{tr} \left[p' \!\!\!\!/ k \!\!/\right]\\
& = 32 \left(p \cdot k \right) \left( p ' \cdot k\right)
\end{aligned}
$$
where $k \!\!/ = \gamma _{ \mu} k ^{ \mu}, p \!\!/ = \gamma _{ \mu} p ^{ \mu}$
I don't understand how to bring $8p \cdot k$ out of the $ \mathrm{tr}$ in the third line.

All I could recall is one of the trace technology
$$
\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{tr} \gamma ^{ \mu} \gamma ^{ \nu} & =  \mathrm{tr} \left(2 g ^{ \mu\nu}\cdot \mathbf{1}-\gamma ^{\nu} \gamma ^{ \mu}\right)\\
& =  8 g ^{ \mu \nu}- \mathrm{tr} \gamma ^{ \mu} \gamma^{\nu}  
\end{aligned}
$$
or
$$
\mathrm{tr} a \!\!/ b \!\!/ = 4 a \cdot b
$$
But I don't know how to use these relation to calculate the $\mathrm{tr} \left[p' \!\!\!\!/ \gamma ^{\mu}k \!\!/ \gamma ^{ \nu}p \!\!/ \gamma _{ \nu} k \!\!/ \gamma _{ \mu}\right] $

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this supposed to be true for arbitrary $k$, $p$ and $p'$? That seems a bit strange. Because in your second line you have:
$$\mathrm{tr}[4\gamma_\mu p'^\mu \gamma_\nu k^\nu(2p \cdot k - \gamma_\rho p^\rho \gamma_\sigma k^\sigma)] = 8p \cdot k\, \mathrm{tr}(\gamma_\mu p'^\mu \gamma_\nu k^\nu) - 4\mathrm{tr}(\gamma_\mu p'^\mu \gamma_\nu k^\nu\gamma_\rho k^\rho \gamma_\sigma p^\sigma)\,,$$
where we can pull out the $8 p \cdot k$ since it's just a number, not a matrix. The second term in the above equation doesn't seem to vanish in general though. One way you can compute it is to decompose a product of two gamma matrices in its symmetric and anti-symmetric part. Let me define:
$$\gamma_{(\mu} \gamma_{\nu)} := \frac{1}{2}(\gamma_\mu\gamma_\nu + \gamma_\nu \gamma_\mu)\,, \qquad \gamma_{[\mu} \gamma_{\nu]} := \frac{1}{2}(\gamma_\mu\gamma_\nu - \gamma_\nu \gamma_\mu)\,,$$
and I am assuming the gamma matrices satisfy:
$$\gamma_{(\mu} \gamma_{\nu)} = g_{\mu\nu} \mathrm{id}\,,$$
where $\mathrm{id}$ is the identity matrix. Now, $$\gamma_\mu k^\mu \gamma_\nu k^\nu = (\gamma_{(\mu} \gamma_{\nu)} + \gamma_{[\mu} \gamma_{\nu]}) k^\mu k^\nu = \gamma_{(\mu} \gamma_{\nu)} k^\mu k^\nu\,,$$
because $k^\mu k^\nu$ is symmetric, so you get $$\gamma_\mu k^\mu \gamma_\nu k^\nu = k^2 \mathrm{id}\,.$$ Now the term with four gamma matrices becomes:
$$\mathrm{tr}(\gamma_\mu p'^\mu \gamma_\nu k^\nu\gamma_\rho k^\rho \gamma_\sigma p^\sigma) = k^2\mathrm{tr}(\gamma_\mu p'^\mu \gamma_\sigma p^\sigma) = 4k^2 (p' \cdot p)\,.$$
Unless I have made some miscalculation (quite possible), this doesn't seem to vanish.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Your answer is very instructive, making it clear about how to calculate the trace. It is my mistake for not providing the background information. Just as lewton said, k-square is equal to 0, because it stands for photon mass.

Answer (score 1):

The first formula comes from Section 5.5 of Peskin & Schroeder. I will demonstrate how to get the third line.

\begin{aligned}
 \mathrm{tr} \left[4 p' \!\!\!\!/ k \!\!/ \left(2 p \cdot k - k \!\!/ p \!\!/\right)\right]&=\mathrm{tr}\left[8 (p\cdot k)p'\!\!\!\!/k\!\!\!/-4p'\!\!\!\!/k\!\!\!/k\!\!\!/p\!\!/\right]\\
& = 8 p \cdot k \ \mathrm{tr} \left[p' \!\!\!\!/ k \!\!/\right]-4\mathrm{tr}[p'\!\!\!\!/k\!\!\!/k\!\!\!/p\!\!/]\\
\end{aligned}

Then we need to show that
$ \mathrm{tr}[p'\!\!\!\!/k\!\!\!/k\!\!\!/p\!\!/]=0$.

\begin{aligned}
\mathrm{tr}[p'\!\!\!\!/k\!\!\!/k\!\!\!/p\!\!/]&=\mathrm{tr}[\gamma^\mu \gamma^\nu \gamma^\rho \gamma^\sigma]p'_\mu k_\nu k_\rho p_\sigma\\
&=4(g^{\mu\nu}g^{\rho\sigma}-g^{\mu\rho}g^{\nu\sigma}+g^{\mu\sigma}g^{\nu\rho})p'_\mu k_\nu k_\rho p_\sigma\quad \text{(page 134)}\\
&=4\left[(p'\cdot k)(k\cdot p)-(p'\cdot k)(k\cdot p)+(p'\cdot p)k^2\right]\\
&=0 \quad (\text{the square of the photon mass is } k^2=0)
\end{aligned}

The last two formulae in your question can not be used to calculate the trace of eight $\gamma$ matrices directly. You should always use the anticommutation relation $\{\gamma^\mu,\gamma^\nu\}=2g^{\mu\nu}$ to reduce the amount of $\gamma$ matrices.